# Using a custom scoring function with pandas groupby to create a column in another dataframe

Tags: pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

This is my partial df=

```
dStart         y_test    y_pred
2018-01-01       1         2
2018-01-01       2         2
2018-01-02       3         3
2018-01-02       1         2
2018-01-02       2         3
```

I want to create a column in another dataframe (df1) with the Mathews Correlation Coefficient of each unique dStart.

```
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef

def mcc_func(y_test,y_pred):
            return matthews_corrcoef(df[y_test].values,df[y_pred].values)
df1['mcc']=df.groupby('dStart').apply(mcc_func('y_test','y_pred'))
```

This function doesn't work -- I think because the function returns a float, and 'apply' wants to use the function on the groupby data itself, but I can't figure out how to give the right function to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the function within the `grouped` object -

```
g = df.groupby('dStart')
g.apply(lambda x: matthews_corrcoef(x['y_test'], x['y_pred']))

#OUTPUT
#dStart
#2018-01-01    0.0
#2018-01-02    0.0
#dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` with `lambda` function:

```
df = (df.groupby(['dStart']).apply(lambda x: matthews_corrcoef(x['y_test'], x['y_pred']))
        .reset_index(name='Matthews_corrcoef'))

print(df)
       dStart  Matthews_corrcoef
0  2018-01-01                0.0
1  2018-01-02                0.0
```